# When should I write "some stratagems" and when "some stratagem"?

Tags: phrases, nouns, grammatical-number

Instances of "some stratagems":
[1](https://books.google.com/books?id=wnpPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA386&dq=some%20stratagems&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HWeyVNSZMevMygO794LwCg&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=some%20stratagems&f=false)
,
[2](https://books.google.com/books?id=z6R1cmvVkMYC&pg=PA208&dq=some%20stratagems&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HWeyVNSZMevMygO794LwCg&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=some%20stratagems&f=false)
,
[3](https://books.google.com/books?id=JkVIBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA213&dq=some%20stratagems&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rXSyVOH1Bsq1oQTRoYGICA&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=some%20stratagems&f=false)
,
[4](https://books.google.com/books?id=7dBqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA34&dq=some%20stratagems&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wHSyVPu9ONHSoATEiYKIAQ&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q=some%20stratagems&f=false)

Instances of "some stratagem":
[1](https://books.google.com/books?id=lG0yAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA97&dq=some%20stratagem&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_GayVMqGI4rhywOKh4GgBg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=some%20stratagem&f=false)
,
[2](https://books.google.com/books?id=lmpVAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA16&dq=some%20stratagem&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_GayVMqGI4rhywOKh4GgBg&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=some%20stratagem&f=false)
,
[3](https://books.google.com/books?id=Raw74CWREkkC&pg=PT138&dq=some%20stratagem&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rGeyVNqNAYXYywPr_4I4&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=some%20stratagem&f=false)
,
[4](https://books.google.com/books?id=InHCBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT69&dq=some%20stratagem&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rGeyVNqNAYXYywPr_4I4&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=some%20stratagem&f=false)

Is "stratagem" plural noun itself? (like phenomena) If so, is it possible to use "s" to make it plural again? Which form of plural is correct for "stratagem"?

Comment: *Phenomenon* is the singular of *phenomena*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Stratagem* is an ordinary noun, not a mass-noun, and has a standard plural form of *stratagems*.

The reason that you see both "some stratagem" and "some stratagems" is because they mean different things.  Imagine that there is a set of 10 possible strategems that will help to capture a flag.  If I say

> He used some stratagem to capture the flag.

This means that out of that collection of possible stratagems, one was selected, but we don't know which one.

If I say

> He used some strategems to capture the flag.

This means that out of that collection of possible strategems, more than one was selected; we still don't know which ones, nor how many, just that more than one were selected.

Similarly, from one of your examples:

> They had to use some strategem to deceive their agents in order to help us

This is talking about how "they" had to go through a certain amount of planning and plotting in order to successfully deceive someone.  We don't know, or even care, exactly what they did; the key is that they had to make some amount of effort to come up with a stratagem ("[a trick or plan for deceiving an enemy or for achieving a goal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stratagem)"<sub>*[m-w.com]*</sub>), but they were successful.

From another example:

> Some stratagems can be practiced on broad audiences such as the entire staff or student body...

This is talking about a large collection of possible stratagems, and saying that there is a subset of them that are useful when working with a large group of people.  (Conversely, some other stratagems are much more effective when dealing only with individuals.)

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: descriptive of how I've heard it used, not an accepted definition)

I've seen *stratagem* used most frequently more like a *tactic* -- perhaps as a piece of an overall strategy.  As such, it's generally used as a singular.  I haven't found any definition which claims it to be plural, nor do any of your four examples seem to necessarily imply that it's plural.